# using class to calculate average of a list of entry in python

Tags: python, class, oop

I have to use the class method in python to calculate the average age, height, and weight of a list of 2 school classes and compare them.

In order to calculate the average ages, I used the following code:

```
from statistics import mean

class Student():
    counter = 0
    def __init__ (self, age, height, weight):
        Student.counter += 1
        self.age = age
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight

class Class_a(Student):

    def av_a():
        temp = []
        for i in range (n):
            temp.append(class_a[i].age)
        m_a = (mean(temp))
        return  m_a


class_a = []

n = 2 
age_a = ['15', '99'] 
height_a = ['123', '144'] 
weight_a = ['33', '28']

for i in range (n):
    class_a.append(Class_a(float(age_a[i]), float(height_a[i]), float(weight_a[i])))


print(Class_a.av_a())
```

It would be highly appreciated if anyone reviews the code and let me know the best way to do such a calculation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Where are you stuck? See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace `Class_a` with a kind of collection that would hold multiple `Student` instances. In this case, no need to inherit from `Student`:

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self, age, height, weight):
        self.age = int(age)
        self.height = int(height)
        self.weight = int(weight)

class Students():
    def __init__(self, *students):
        self.students = list(students)

    # implementation of height() and weight() would be similar
    def age(self):
        return mean(map(lambda x: x.age, self.students))

    def add(self, student):
        self.students.append(student)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.students)
```

This way you can initialize with some students:

```
students = Students(Student('15', '123', '33'))
```

And/or add more later:

```
students.add(Student('99', '144', '28'))
students.add(Student('20', '134', '22'))
```

You have access to the averages at any time:

```
print(students.age())
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply; however, when I want to add a student, I am receiving this error message: 'Student' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Hey @HasanA., make sure you apply `add` on a `Students` (with an `s`) not a `Student`!

Comment: I copied the same code that you shared. please see https://imgur.com/0RNFBAY

Comment: My bad, `Students`' constructor takes a *list*, either define `students` as `students = Students(Student('15', '123', '33'))` or look at my corrected answer to allow `Students` to recieve a variable number of `Student`s with the star operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, num, age, heigth, weigth):
        self.number = num
        self.age = age
        self.heigth = heigth
        self.weigth = weigth
    def cal_average(self):
        return(sum(self.age)/len(self.age), sum(self.heigth)/len(self.heigth), sum(self.weigth)/len(self.weigth))
```

### example

```
a = Student(5,[16, 17, 15, 16, 17],[180, 175, 172, 170, 165],[67, 72, 59, 62, 55])
avg1, avg2, avg3 = a.cal_average()
```